# Windows 7 Application Experience Service keep stopping preventing MSVC from linking

Tags: visual-c++, service, development-environment, windows-7-x64

Annoyingly, when developing in MSVC2010, my EXE will not link (ie cannot emit output file) because the application experience service in Windows 7 has stopped.

I've no idea how these two things can be related, but i've been "fixing" it my manually restarting the process in the Windows service manager. Then i can link. At a random time later it will happen again. the process is set to automatic by default.

i've had enough of this madness. does anyone have any ideas? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this: http://gauravpandey.com/wordpress/?p=291 it should work. it has atleast worked for me though I have not really understood the relationship between the two issues.

Comment: It works for a while when i restart the application experience (as described), but then it stops again. I've not managed to solve this. the current solution is to buy a new PC :/